# nested resources in laravel not worked

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I want to have nested resources like that:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manage', 'middleware' => ['role:boss']], function () 
{
   Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticleController');

   Route::group(['prefix' => '/articles', 'as' => 'articles.'], function () {
        Route::resource('/types', 'ArticleTypeController');
    });
});
```

But nested route for "article/type" doesn't work, I check my ArticleTypeController outside the "article" route and work.

I really confused, Everybody can help me?

and here is my controller:

```
class ArticleTypeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $types = ArticleType::all();
        return view('manage.articles.types.index')->withtypes($types);
    }
}
```

Comment: `/article/type` or `/articles/types`? Check how you're defining and make sure you're using the correct value (plural vs non-plural)

Comment: no Tim it's plural

Comment: `But nested route for "article/type" doesn't work` What's wrong with that statement? Should that statement read **article/type** or **articles/types**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manage', 'middleware' => ['role:boss']], function () 
{
   Route::get('articles/types', 'ArticleTypeController@articleTypeMethod');

   Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');    
   Route::resource('articles.types', 'ArticleTypeController');
});
```

for nested resources use `articles.types`. plural naming is good. 
now that `manage/articles` and `manage/articles/1/types` will work.

If you want to put a custom route, put it above the resource route if the controller has been used as a resource. see the `articles/types [GET]` route which maps to `ArticleTypeController`'s `articleTypeMethod`. now this way `http://localhost.com/manage/articles/types` should work

here is the [5.1 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources) and it has been removed from documentation of 5.5. but have a look at what Taylor said about it [here](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/926174164070912000)

it's not recommended on REST to use index function for `articles/types`, a nested resources `index` method is used like `articles/{id}/types`. 
for `articles/types` you need to create a new method.

but if you still want to do it like that. just make it like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manage', 'middleware' => ['role:boss']], function () 
{
   Route::get('articles/types', 'ArticleTypeController@index');

   Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');    
   Route::resource('articles.types', 'ArticleTypeController', ['except' => ['index']]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But specifically I want to use manage/articles/types, that's my issue

Comment: is that what you want?

Comment: Isn't it possible that using group or resource anyway?

Comment: as it is a custom route it can't be used as a REST resource route. you need to create a specific method and call with http method to that route as I have mentioned. resource routes are just index,create,store,edit,update,destroy. check the documentation link I have provided :)

Comment: did it solve? if so please mark it as the correct answer. if need more help let me know :)

Comment: I check " Route::get('articles/types', 'ArticleTypeController@articleTypeMethod');" right now, and unfortunately the route is inaccessible, It somehow weird for me since when I remove "articles" it worked!!!!

Comment: could you update your question to include controllers?

Comment: do you have articleTypeMethod() on your ArticleTypeController.

Comment: Yes I have a index function my buddy

Comment: you want to use index function like that. but it's against REST. a nested resources index method is used like articles/{id}/types. for articles/types you need to create an new method. but if you still want to do it like that. just make it like this Route::get('articles/types', 'ArticleTypeController@index'); and use except on the resource definition. to do that change resource definition to Route::resource('articles.types', 'ArticleTypeController', ['except' => ['index']]); let me add this to answer

Comment: I got it. Thanks!